# <identifier> expected compile error

Tags: java, android

I am trying to figure out why I get a compile error on the code below:

```
package com....;
public enum Something { //says error: <identifier> expected on this line

private String myInput;

public Something(String paramString) {
    this.myInput = paramString;
}

public String getInputName() {
    return this.myInput;
}
}
```

Comment: did you mean class instead of enum?

Comment: It is code I inherited and it comes with enum

Answer (score 5):

You have couple of problem with your enum declaration , first `enum` constructor cannot be public and second you need to add `;` before private field. E.g.

```
public enum Something {
    ;
    private String myInput;

    Something(String paramString) {
        this.myInput = paramString;
    }

    public String getInputName() {
        return this.myInput;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha. Adding ; fixes the problem. Didnt know that there must be a ; before private variable. Learned something. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helps :) . You can always accept it as answer if it answered your question

Comment: why is the `;` necessary?

Comment: @BenKnoble To end the `enum constant` declaration block . Please note that in enum `All the constants must be declared on the top, they can't come last or in between enum definition`

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems you are not using enumerations, change "enum" to "class".

```
package com....;
public class Something {

    private String myInput;

    public Something(String paramString) {
        this.myInput = paramString;
    }

    public String getInputName() {
        return this.myInput;
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing to class is indeed compiling, I suppose this fixes my problem. But still, why wouldnt it compile with enum?